# How to optimize fetch from cursor with 5 millions raw

Tags: python, pyodbc, database-cursor

I got a table from MSSQL with 5M rows and when I fetch all the rows of this table, this take me 2~3 minutes. I want (if possible) to optimize that.

That's my code :

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM MyTable")

rows = cursor.fetchall() # that takes 2~3 minutes

# some code for setup the output that take only few seconds
```

I already tried, to used :

```
while True:
    rows = cursor.fetchmany(500000)
    
    if not rows: 
        break

    # Do some stuff
```

And Also with fetchone.

But again i'm between 2-3 mins :/ How to optimize that ? Maybe using thread but I don't know how.

thanks for your help.

Comment: Ask yourself if you really do need to retrieve every column for all 5 million rows at once. If so, then that's going to take some time regardless of how you implement it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can limit the number of lines returned by your query even if you have to make several calls to your database.

About the *Threads*, you have several solutions:

1. A single connection but a different cursor for each Thread
2. One connection for each Thread and one cursor from that connection

In any case you need a [`ThreadedConnectionPool`](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/pool.html). Here is a small example of one of the ways to do it

```py
import psycopg2
from psycopg2 import pool
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep

threaded_connection_pool = None
thread_table = list()

def get_new_connection():
    global threaded_postgreSQL_pool
    connection = None

    while not isinstance(connection, psycopg2.extensions.connection):
        try:
            connection = threaded_postgreSQL_pool.getconn()
        except pool.PoolError:
            sleep(10)  # Wait a free connection

    return connection, connection.cursor()


def thread_target():
    connection, cursor = get_new_connection()

    with connection, cursor:
        # Do some stuff
        pass


threaded_connection_pool = psycopg2.pool.ThreadedConnectionPool(
    # YOUR PARAM
    )


for counter_thread in range(10):
    thread = Thread(
        target=thread_target,
        name=f"Thread n°{counter_thread}"
    )
    thread_table.append(thread)
    thread.start()

#
# Do many more stuff
#


for thread in thread_table:
    thread.join()

# End
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use the first solution "A single connection but a different cursor for each Thread"

For that : I have to do something like that ?

```
result = []
cursor = connection.cursor()

def fetch_cursor(cursor):
    global result
    rows = cursor.fetchall()
    if rows:
       result += beautify_output(rows)

######### THIS CODE BELOW IS INSIDE A FUNCTION ######

thread_table = []
limit = 1000000
offset = 0
sql = "SELECT * FROM myTABLE"

while True:
    try:
        cursor.execute(f"{sql} LIMIT {limit} OFFSET {offset}")
    except Exception as e:
        break
    
    offset += limit

    thread = Thread(target=fetch_cursor, args=(cursor,))
    thread_table.append(thread)
    thread.start()

for thread in thread_table:
    thread.join()

print(result)
```

So something like that should work ? (I will try that tommorow)

Comment: I think some parts are missing in this excerpt, here no cursor is created for each thread, they all share the same.
The choice of a way of doing (one or more connections) will depend on the way of doing multiprocessing([documentation](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#thread-and-process-safety))